# How do I convert alphanumeric to digits while keeping actual digits in the string intact

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to convert a column that has alphanumeric values to digits

```
0 newyork2510        2
1 boston76w2         1
2 chicago785dw       1
3 san891dwn39210114  1
4 f2391rpg           1
```

so that

```
0 newyork2510  2
```

should look like

```
0 14523251518112510 2
```

similarly, rest of the whole second column.

I can only do the following which only helps me converting alphabets to digits

```
for character in input:
    number = ord(character) - 96
    output.append(number)
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `replace` with `regex=True`:

```
# map the char to string integers
char_map = {chr(i): str(j) for j,i in enumerate(range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1), 1)}

# apply the mapping to the column
df['col1'] = df['col1'].replace(char_map, regex=True)
```

Output:

```
   col0                   col1  col2
0     0      14523251518112510     2
1     1       2151920151476232     1
2     2         38931715785423     1
3     3  191148914231439210114     1
4     4             6239118167     1
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I have not only small caps but all caps (A-Z) as well and at some point other special characters i.e. ö, ü etc?

Comment: You gotta add them to charmap manually